# Excel IF statement with calculation in condition always gives FALSE

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm stuck with a weird formula that always gives false, i even copied the cells to another sheet and end up with the same result.
Did the needed checks to validate the numbers, they are equal and deduction result is ZERO
However, in the IF condition, it always gives false. both cells are currently as values with no additional decimal values.

What would be wrong in this?

Below screenshot along with the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16on-11bwTWEwQSGezdew7OPbvH1MObYX/view?usp=sharing) itself uploaded to google drive.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: try `=IF((H11-H12)=0,"True","False")`

Comment: What do you get for `=H11-H12=0` ?

Answer (score 1):

When evaluating the formula of your spreadsheet, the result of `H11-H12` is not equal to 0 but `1.16415321826935E-10`. That is why the result of the whole formula is always False.

Deleting the content of `H11`, then retyping the number solves the issue. Or, if deleting is not an option, then rounding the result as suggested by @Engineer Toast in the comments with the formula `=IF(ROUND(H11-H12,2)=0,"True","False")`should also give TRUE.

[image]

Comment: I imagine OP could do something like `=IF(ROUND(H11-H12,2)=0,"True","False"` if they want a solution without having to re-enter their data.

Comment: @EngineerToast You are correct. I have edited the answer and added your suggestion.